# Convergence of Riemann maps

Tags: complex-analysis

For $\epsilon > 0$, let $K_\epsilon = \{e^{i\theta} : \theta \in [0,\pi-\epsilon]\}$ be an almost-semicircle. Let $D_\epsilon = H \setminus K_\epsilon$, where $H$ is the upper half plane. Let $\phi_\epsilon : D_\epsilon \rightarrow H$ be the Riemann map normalized so that $\lim_{z\rightarrow\infty} \phi_\epsilon(z) -z = 0$. Let $\psi_\epsilon = \phi_\epsilon/\phi_\epsilon'(0)$ on the intersection of $A$ of the unit disk with the upper half plane. I am trying to show that $\psi_\epsilon$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $A$ to a conformal map from $A$ to $H$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Intuitively, as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $D_\epsilon$ approaches a domain with two connected components, and an appropriately normalize map should approach a biholomorphism on each. But, I do not have much of an idea as to how to turn this intuition into a proof. Does anyone have any suggestions? Even better, are there any general results about the limits of Riemann maps on domains which are "almost disconnected" which can be applied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard tool is the [Carathéodory kernel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory_kernel_theorem). It operates with a notion of the limit of domains with a distinguished interior point; the same point that is also used to normalize the Riemann map.

So, if you normalize $\phi_\epsilon$ so that $\phi_\epsilon(i/2)=i$, they will converge to a conformal map of $H\cap \{z:|z|<1\}$ onto $H$. And if you normalize them so that $\phi_\epsilon(2i)=i$, they will converge to a conformal map of $H\cap \{z:|z|>1\}$ onto $H$.

Normalization by a boundary value of a derivative is not as reliable: it gives less control on the map. If you have  a reason to use this particular normalization, comment and I'll try to come up with something.

---

Additional details:

1. In Wikipedia, the Carathéodory kernel theorem is stated for maps from the unit disk $D$ to a sequence of domains. It applies just as well to maps from halfplane $H$ to a sequence of domains, because they can composed with a fixed map $D\to H$.
2. So, the theorem applies to the inverses of $\phi_\epsilon$, normalized, for example, by $\phi_\epsilon(i)=z_0$. The kernel of the sequence $\phi_\epsilon^{-1}(H)$ depends on the choice of this normalization: if $|z_0|<1$, it is the upper half-disk, if $|z_0|>1$, it is the upper half-plane minus the half-disk.
3. One can infer the convergence of $\phi_\epsilon$ from the convergence of $\phi_\epsilon^{-1}$. Rouche's theorem and Hurwitz's theorems come to mind as  possible tools here. But it may be more practical to read a more detailed discussion of kernel convergence, either in *Geometric theory of functions of a complex variable* by Goluzin or in *Univalent functions* by Duren.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can see how to get uniform convergence to some univalent function now, but how do we know that the "kernel" in the theorem is actually the whole upper half plane? All I can say about the images of the $\psi_\epsilon$ is that they contain the half-disk of radius 1/4 (by the Koebe 1/4 theorem).

Comment: @user15464 I added some details. The point is to look at the kernels of $D_\epsilon$ themselves, which are known domains.